# Insert records into temp table from msdb.dbo.syssessions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't have access to `msdb.dbo` tables so I am trying to insert records in temp table

Example

For `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity` I did as

```
Create table #Sysjobactivity (All columns here)

Insert into #sysjobactivity

Execute msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobactivity---worked fine for this
```

But for `msdb.dbo.syssessions` I am unable to insert

```
Create table #syssessions(all columns here)

Insert into #syssessions

execute msdb.dbo.help_sessions
```

But I can't see any msdb.dbo.help_sessions , is there a way we can insert

Because of an access issue, I am trying to go through this route.

Comment: If you don't have access to the table, you can't `INSERT` that data into another table; if you could that would be a pretty fundamental security flaw.

Comment: how can he access even sysjobactivity, since in the sp_help_jobactivity procedure it reads from sessions?

Comment: Hmm alright, makes sense, but if procedure have used dynamic sql to read from the session table, it would fail i guess? I kinda remember granting proc rights is seldom enough

Comment: I guess the solution for SQL2023 is to ask someone who has rights to write you a procedure that can access the data you need. Or give you the rights to the tables themselves. Though, not sure why you need this table, since you get all useful columns from the sp_help_jobactivity already

Comment: @siggemannen because I am trying get max(agent_start_date),trying to get like               join msdb.dbo.syssessions s on s.session_id=a.sessionid(from jobactivity)                          join (select max(agent_start_date) as max_date from msdb.dbo.sessions)s_max on s.agent_date_max=s_max.agent_max_date

Comment: I think the question should be, why do you want to know when sql server agent started :D Only reason i ever fetched session data is to make sure step history that were marked as unfinished were part of the latest session and not some old session where SQL Agent got killed